# Creating Junit tests when controller methods need authentication

Tags: junit, spring-security

I have followed a course on TDD and have written my junit tests and all was working well. Since then I have now made some methods on my `UserController` class, so that only certain roles can access them, such as a method to create a new `User`

Now that I have done this some tests are now failing as I am receiving `401 UNAUTHORIZED` rather than `200 OK` I understand why, but not sure how to properly test these methods.

I have tried the following which I thought would authenticate a fake user with the correct role and then run the methods, but I still get `401 UNAUTHORIZED` I have made a separate class which holds some of the methods to create valid and invalid entities such as `Users`

```
@Test
    public void postUser_whenUserIsValid_receiveOK() {
        //Save society to the database
        societyService.save(TestUtil.createValidSociety());
        //Create new user
        User user = TestUtil.createValidUser();
        //Authenticate user
        authenticate("test-user");

        ResponseEntity<Object> response = postSignup(user, Object.class);

        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

My authenticate method,

```
private void authenticate(String username) {
        testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate()
                .getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(username, "P4ssword"));
    }
```

and my postSignup method,

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postSignup(Object request, Class<T> response) {
        return testRestTemplate.postForEntity(API_1_0_USERS, request, response);
    }
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: why not start by reading the spring security reference documentation/manual which contains an entire chapter on testing? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/method.html#test-method-withmockuser

Comment: could you add controller and spring security configuration code also?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that some of the methods inside the `UserController`has `@PreAuthorize(..)` annotation:

```java
@Controller

public class UserController {

    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public void dummy() {

    }
}
```

And also i am assuming that your access denied handler is redirecting the un-authorized requests to the `/login` page:

```java
public class YourAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(...) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login);
    }
}
```

Lastly, I am assuming that you are using JUNIT 5

Now, you can test with mockito like this:

```java
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.*;

@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    void otherUsersCanNotAccess() throws Exception {
        String url = "/user";

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder req = get(url);
        req.with(user("user").roles("ROLE_CUSTOMER"));
        mockMvc.perform(req)
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/login"))
                ;
    }

    @Test
    void onlyAccessibleByAdmin() throws Exception {
        String url = "/user";

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder req = get(url);
        req.with(user("admin").roles("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        mockMvc.perform(req)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                ;

    }
}
```